# $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path is $null in PowerGUI script editor

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powergui

When trying to debug my powershell script in the powerGUI script editor (2.0.0.1082) the  $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path is $null. 
It works when running the script via powershell. 
Running it in Powershell_ise.exe (on one of our servers) also works fine.

Have anyone else had the same problem or know what's wrong?

Here's my powershell version:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.4927
BuildVersion                   6.1.7600.16385
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Server version:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.3082
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: FYI: I read somewhere that it would be null when calling it from a function. I haven't done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Download the latest version of PowerGUI from http://powergui.org and the issue will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for following this up. :)

Comment: I'm running the latest version (3.5.0.2293) and still seem to have this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` object changes depending on the context of its execution. In this case, `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` will only return something if called from the `$script:` scope, since that is the only valid scope to determine the directory from which the code was executed.

Therefore, the solution here would either be to use `$script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` or `$MyInvocation.ScriptName`.

---

**EDIT**

Running this in the PowerShell ISE works as expected, as you get the same result if you run it in the PowerShell console:

```
function Main
{
    Write-Host ("MyCommand.Path from function: " + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
    Write-Host ("ScriptName from function: " + $MyInvocation.ScriptName)
}

Main

Write-Host ("MyCommand.Path from script scope: " + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
Write-Host ("ScriptName from script scope: " + $MyInvocation.ScriptName)
```

Output is:

```
MyCommand.Path from function: 
ScriptName from function: C:\temp\Test.ps1
MyCommand.Path from script scope: C:\temp\Test.ps1
ScriptName from script scope:
```

I haven't used PowerGUI, but if you don't get the same output, then its probably a bug.

Comment: None of them gives me anything but $null. And as $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path is called in the first line in the script outside any function, my limited powershell knowledge tells me it's already in the $script scope. I think it's actually a bug in ScriptEditor, as it works fine when run from the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

call your script from another script file:
http://powergui.org/message.jspa?messageID=28988#28988

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using Get-PSCallStack.  The InvocationInfo property of each layer in the callstack is the equivilent to $myInvocation

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a useful tool. When running the script from the ScriptEditor debugger, the Command from Get-PSCallStack is '.', but when running the script from the prompt it is the name of my script.